# How to decide TabId and ModuleId in Globals.NavigateURL in DotnetNuke?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I am damn confuse in `TabId` and `ModuleId` which need to pass as parameters in `Globals.NavigateURL`.

I have created a project with 2 UserControl. Now I want to navigate in button click event of first UserControl.

I have reviewed some reference. Most of them suggest to pass `TabId, Key and ModuleId`. I know `Key` but I don't know what is `TabId` and `ModuleId` and how to get it in my `.cs` file of usercontrol.

Can anybody please suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answering [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437658/how-to-redirect-to-another-viewusercontrol-ascx-in-dotnetnuke/40444708#40444708), I told you that the following two lines of code are equivalent:

```
string miUrl = base.EditUrl("ModuleInfo");
string miUrl = DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(base.TabId, "ModuleInfo", String.Format("mid={0}", base.ModuleId));
```

If you inherit from PortalModuleBase, you have access to TabId and ModuleId in the base class.  If you only need to navigate to a module control (view) in the same module, base.EditUrl() works fine.  You need to use NavigateUrl() if you need to navigate to another module or to another page (tab).

Answer (score 1):

If your module is set up correctly, these should be available to you as they are inherited.

From your question it seems you don't know enough about the framework.  I recommend that you get a copy of the DNN 7 book.  It's relevant to DNN 8, and should start you off correctly.  There are other things available: the wiki and the developer resources there.

Comment: Thanks but just reading is not enough. I must go through examples to check the actual problem raises while develop.